# Completely understanding work and movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am studying work and energy and I have a problem concerning work executed on a certain body.Let's say we've got a body like this:
[image: a rectangle with some red and one green arrows going from it]

The red arrows are forces acting on this body,the green arrow shows the direction in which the body is moving.I've got this example in my textbook and the given question is how much work is executed on this body,with a given distance.
Now follow the way this is solved in the textbook,the way I solved it and why I think I got a different answer.I'd like to know if I understand all correctly.

**My attempt:**

We know that work done on a body is net force acting on it multiplied by the distance the body moves for:
$$A=s*F$$
I get the net force and multiply.

**Textbook:**
Only the forces working in the direction in which the body is moving are performing any work.The forces working perpendicularly on the direction do not perform work.You take the projections of the forces on the direction,calculate them with trigonometry and then multiply this by distance.

The solutions do not come out the same.
**My idea why:**
If I look at the net force I see it doesn't really work in the direction given for the body's moving.But because there are certainly no other forces(confirmed also by the textbook),the body must in fact be moving in the direction of the force as it is also not rotating or anything of that kind.So I guess the question the textbook wanted to ask is *how much work is done on the body in the given direction* and not *what is the total work performed on this body moving in this direction*.
This is a very small difference in the text,but it might be the reason.
In other words I have been calculating the body's energy change     $$\Delta W=A$$ while they calculated the energy needed to move the body in that green coordinate,which is just a part of its total diagonal move.
Please let me know if my hypothesis is anywhere near the truth and what I'm missing.

Comment: "We know that work done on a body is net force acting on it multiplied by the distance the body moves for": It's the dot product of the net force and the displacement of the body. In other words it is only the component of the net force in the direction of motion that does work.

Comment: The two methods give the same result, you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: In a free body diagram all force vectors must start from body COM point, that's the essence of this type of diagram so that it could be seen easily how force vectors will add. Please re-draw chart if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The textbook is correct. The total work on a body is defined as the product of the body's displacement with the component of net force **in the direction of the displacement**. Mathematically this is expressed with the dot product,

$$W = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{s} = Fs\cos(\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the force $\vec{F}$ and the displacement  $\vec{s}$. The equation $W = Fs$ is only true when the force and displacement are in the same direction.

For example, if you carry a book across the room at constant height and velocity, you do no work on the book. Even though you exert a vertical force to support the book, it is perpendicular to the horizontal displacement, so $W = Fs\cos(90^\circ) = 0$.

Comment: But how do you mean that?First,in my question the net force is NOT working in the direction that the textbook said the body is moving.Second,the finger supporting the book actually does produce a force,but it is opposite to gravity.If there was no gravity,the finger would actually be working and the book would gain height.So are you sure this is right?

Comment: @PlamenBajsić Addressing your first point, the direction of net force tells you the direction of the *acceleration*, not the direction of motion. It's perfectly acceptable to have an object move in a direction opposite to the direction of net force.

Comment: @PlamenBajsić Your second point is correct and in agreement with my example. If there was no gravity, the book would be displaced vertically due to the force from your finger. Then your finger would do work on the book. If there is gravity, there's no vertical displacement and you do no work on the book.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) is the Wikipedia page on work if you are still uncertain.

Comment: ,yes,you're right about my points and thanks for the link.Still I'd like to now this:isn't the displacement also subject to the force and acceleration?One component of the net force(the one working in the green direction)does the work,but what about the other,vertical component?I suppose it changes the course of movement and accelerates the body even more?So it actually does some work.But,I don't want to bother you too much,maybe I'll get it by myself after some time.

Comment: @PlamenBajsić I agree with you. If the net force had some vertical component then the body would accelerate in the vertical direction, and after some time would have been displaced vertically. Then the vertical component of the net force does work on the body. However, in the problem above we’re told the body is displaced horizontally, so either the forces in the vertical direction are balanced, or we’re not considering motion in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 0):

> Only the forces working in the direction in which the body is moving
> are performing any work.

Better to say only the *components* of the forces in the direction in which the body is moving are performing any work.

> We know that work done on a body is net force acting on it multiplied
> by the distance the body moves for: $$A=s*F$$ I get the net force and
> multiply.

It is not simply the product of the net force and displacement. *It is the dot product.*, or for a constant net force

$$W = \vec F_{net} \cdot \vec s = F_{net} \cos\theta$$

Where $\theta$$ is the angle between the net force vector and displacement vector.

In the diagram the vertical downward force arrow appears larger than the vertical upward force implying a net downward force associated with the two. But the red force acting upward and to the right has two components: an upward vertical component and a rightward horizontal component.

Since the direction of the body’s movement is strictly horizontally to the right it appears that (1) the vertically upward component cancels the net downward force of the two vertical forces for a net vertical force on the body of zero and (2) The horizontal component to the right must then be greater than the horizontal force acting to the left for a net horizontal force to the right. The end result of all this is a net horizontal force and acceleration to the right.

See the figure below.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in your working.

Assume that three of the forces are $a\hat j, -b\hat j,-c\hat i$ and the fourth force  is of magnitude $d$ at an angle of $\theta$ to the $\hat i$ direction.

[image]

The net force acting on the body is $a\hat j+ (-b\hat j)+(-c\hat i) + d\cos\theta \,\hat i + d \sin\theta j = (d\cos\theta -c)\hat i+(a-b+d\sin \theta )\hat j $

The work done after a displacement of $e\hat i$ is $[ (d\cos\theta -c)\hat i+(a-b+d\sin \theta )\hat j]\cdot [e\hat i]$.

Now $\hat i\cdot \hat i = 1$ and $\hat i\cdot \hat j = 0$

So the work done is $\underbrace{(d\cos\theta -c)}_{\tiny\text{forces in direction of motion}}\times e$